# silverlight doesn't contain intialdirectory

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have silverligh4 application, I need to set the default of openfiledialoge , but I cannot find intialdirectory I simply use it as following

any work around , or even any add to web.config

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this feature was added only in Silverlight 5.

You cannot specify an initial folder is a limitation of the Silverlight 4. For more information please preview this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28VS.95%29.aspx).

> You cannot specify an initial folder for the OpenFileDialog. The first
>   time the OpenFileDialog is displayed for an application, the initial
>   folder is based on the user's settings. Additional displays of the
>   OpenFileDialog for an application use the folder of the last selected
>   file.

Comment: yah , how to handle the default of search even from web,config